# Speech Recognition: recognition.onresult() does not fire

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to follow a tutorial that requires Chrome's Speech Recognition API. The `recognition.onstart` works well, but the `recognition.onresult` is never fired. I am using Javascript.

How can I modify my code ?

(Version of Chrome: 92.0.4515.107).

Javascript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.talk');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = function(){
    console.log('voice is activated');
};

recognition.onresult = function(e){
    console.log(e);
};


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    recognition.start();
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Voice AI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="talk">Talk</button>
    <h3 class="content"></h3>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You try this way

```
  function detectedVoice(){
    var ses = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    ses.interimResults = true;``
    ses.maxAlternatives = 1;
    ses.continuous = true;
    ses.interimResults = true;
    ses.onstart = true;
    ses.onend = function() {
      ses.start();
    };
    ses.onresult = function(e){
      if (event.results.length > 0) {
        sonuc = event.results[event.results.length -1];
        if (sonuc.isFinal) {
          var result = sonuc[0].transcript;
          console.log(result);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```